# Block [...] on template [...] does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When updating from Symfony3.4 to Symfony4 and verifying the operation, the following error occurred.
When I examined the code, there was no definition in base.twig.html, but there was a definition in the file extending layout.html.
It seems that each is defined and used properly.
How should this be fixed?

Error

```
Block "contentBackIcon" on template "base.html.twig" does not exist.
```

layout.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{{ block('contentBackIcon') }}
{% endblock %}
```

①index.html.twig

```
{% extends '@AppBundle/Sp/shop_layout.html.twig' %}

{# contentBackIcon #}
{% block contentBackIcon %}
    {% if not modal %}
    <a class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-left"  href="{{ path("app_shop_default_index")}}" data-ignore="push">
        <span class="icon icon-left-nav"></span>
    </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

②input.html.twig

```
{% extends '@AppBundle/Sp/shop_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block contentBackIcon %}
    <a class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-left"  href="{{ path('app_shop_article_index', {"q": {"articleType": "coordinate"}}) }}" data-ignore="push">
        <span class="icon icon-left-nav"></span>
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

Version
symfony v4.0.15
twig/twig 2.14.3

Comment: Your block need to exist too on your base.html.twig template. Just add on it `{% block BackIcon %}{% endblock %}`
Look here : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/block.html

Comment: How do these files refer to each other? Where does `layout.html.twig` include the definition of that block?

Comment: @NicoHaase I added the code. ```input.html.twig``` also loads ```layout.html.twig``` with extend. I added it to ```base.html.twig``` as advised by @Hamham, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I added it to base.html.twig as below.

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}

            //Add
           {% block contentBackIcon %}{% endblock %} 
      
        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```